# Scala/Akka WSResponse recursively call

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Im trying to parse some data from an API

I have a recursion method that calling to this method

```
 def getJsonValue( url: (String)): JsValue = {
 val builder = new com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
 val client = new play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient(builder.build())
 val newUrl = url.replace("\"", "").replace("|", "%7C").trim
 val response: Future[WSResponse] = client.url(newUrl).get()
 Await.result(response, Duration.create(10, "seconds")).json
}
```

Everything is working well but after **128 method calls**  i'm getting this warning

```
WARNING: You are creating too many HashedWheelTimer instances.  HashedWheelTimer is a shared resource that must be reused across the application, so that only a few instances are created.
```

After about 20 **More calls** im getting  this exception

```
23:24:57.425 [main] ERROR com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient - Unable to instantiate       provider com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.  Trying other providers.
23:24:57.438 [main] ERROR com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient - org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
```

**Questions**

1.Im assuming that the connections didnt closed ??  and therefore i can't create new connections.

2.What will be the correct and the safe way to create those  HTTP calls

Comment: 1) Don't use `Await.result` and 2) don't create a new client for every request.

Comment: the client location is very basic and i completely missed that.
but can you please elaborate more why don't use Await.result?

Comment: Await.result blocks your Thread until the response from the WS call is completely retrieved. If the method gets often called concurrently then your thread pool runs out of threads and your application blocks other requests. You should use a Future instead.

Comment: That true but if i have to do a sync Http and NOT async http ,
would you implement it in another way ?

Comment: The question is, why would you do a sync request?

Comment: im calling for Facebook api  in that case ,so you think it will be better to pass Future and then extract the data ?

Comment: Yes, you should definitively do that. All your external calls should use futures. Do you know http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/?

Comment: If you are in play ecosystem, first you can use [Play WS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS) client (it uses ning as underlying machinery but working with it is much easier than directly using ning). Secondly if you serve responses by play, you can simply use an [async action](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/ScalaAsync) which knows how to serve a future response :) So what you need is to map your `Future`s which can be simply done with `map` and `flatMap`. Blocking the computation will ruin the whole idea of a non-blocking asynchronous http client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Found 2 interesting solutions:

- make sure you are not creating tons of clients with closing them
- the threadPool you are using may be causing this.

My piece of code (commenting that line of code solved, I'm now testing several configurations):

```
  private[this] def withClient(block: NingWSClient => WSResponse): Try[WSResponse] = {
    val config = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder().build()
    val clientConfig = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder(config)
     // .setExecutorService(new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 15, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue[Runnable]))
      .build()
    val client = new NingWSClient(clientConfig)
    val result = Try(block(client))
    client.close()
    result
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for avoiding this you can use different provider.
private AsyncHttpProvider httpProvider =new ApacheAsyncHttpProvider(config);

```
private AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(httpProvider,config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. Before you call your recursive method, you should create `builder` and `client` and pass client to the recursive method, as well as `getJsonValue`. This is what `getJsonValue` should look like:

```
 def getJsonValue(url: String, client: NingWSClient): JsValue = {
   val builder = new com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
   val client = new play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient(builder.build())
   val newUrl = url.replace("\"", "").replace("|", "%7C").trim
   val response: Future[WSResponse] = client.url(newUrl).get()
   Await.result(response, Duration.create(10, "seconds")).json
}
```